# Default sorting options Sort by 'rating' not working in Magento 2.4.1 in ElasticSearch 7.x

Tags: elasticsearch, ratings, magento2.4.1, product-sorting

I have installed Magento 2.4.1 Open source edition with Elastic Search 7.x version.

- Magento admin -> Stores -> Attributes -> Product
- Find default 'rating' attribute and set 'Use in filter options' to Yes
- Clear cache if needed
- Open category/product listing page
- Change the sort option to 'Rating'

Result which I'm getting is that product position remains same even if i change direction ASC/DESC

https://www.domainexample.com/category.html?product_list_order=rating&product_list_dir=desc
https://www.domainexample.com/category.html?product_list_order=rating&product_list_dir=asc

I have done re-index multiple times and verified elastic search mapping as well.

Just to note that site does not have any custom/third-party modules.

Tried to add `weight` as well but that is also not working.

Ref. issues(sort by quantity and sort by quantity) I found

1. https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/31775
2. https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/28924

Comment: This may be related to the officially confirmed bug [#31043](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/31043).